# Port Forwarding stops working after several minutes

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, port-forwarding

I am currently having issues with port forwarding.
I've got a raspberry pi with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, it's running apache and ftp servers.
I've configured a static ip for my system and configured my router to forward the outside requests to port 80, 22 and 21 in order to access my servers and use SSH from outside networks.
It worked fine until recently, now the port forwarding just randomly stops working after several minutes.
The changes to NAT settings I've made are still present in the router admin page and I can still access my web-servers or perform remote control from LAN using the same IP address, however trying to perform these actions from outside networks using my router's public ip simply results in error 110 and connection timeout.
Rebooting the router does no good, however rebooting the system itself actually temporarily resolves the issue.
I don't know what could be causing this problem and how to fix this, the only changes I've made recently were enabling ssl, redirecting all http requests to https and setting password for apache.
I've reverted all the changes already, however the issue still persists.
Is there anything that can be done besides reinstalling Ubuntu completely? Is it even the problem with the device itself or is it the router that's causing the issue?

Comment: Have you forwarded https (tcp 443) port too ? you may check the destination ip of forwarders

Comment: Yes, I did. And I don't think that could be the problem because I've disabled the https protocol already, plus ftp and ssh can't be accessed from outside too.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was sshguard causing the problem by blocking all requests from my public ip address. Problem was solved by whitelisting the ip address.